# Node.js Express.js MongoDB: route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to set up a MEAN (mongodb, express, nodejs, angular6(CLI)) app. Trying to post user signup form data to mongo database, but its throwing an error. It is my first MEAN app, trying to learn.

Do I miss something here?

> Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

**server.js**

Here is `server.js` file.

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser =  require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();

var api = require('./server/routes/api');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/meanshopcart')));

app.use('/api', api);

app.post('/sign-up', api.signup);

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/meanshopcart/index.html'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);
//app.listen(port, function(){
//    console.log("Server is running..!!");
//});

server.listen(port, function(err){
    if(err){
       return console.log('something bad happened', err);
    }
    console.log("Server is running..!!");
});
```

**Routes Folder(routes/api.js)**

my routes folder `./server/routes/api.js`

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/users');

const db = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/meanshopapp';
mongoose.connect(db, function(err){
    console.log("mongo connection done");
    if(err){
        console.log("Error.."+err);
    }
});

router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    console.log("get api ");
    User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if (err) throw err;

  // object of all the users
   console.log(users);
  });
    res.send(users);
});

exports.signup = function(req, res, next){
    console.log("new user entered");

    var newUser = new User();
    newUser.name = req.body.name;
     newUser.email = req.body.email;
     newUser.password = req.body.password;
     newUser.phoneNo = req.body.phone;
     newUser.address = req.body.address;
    
    newUser.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log("error saving user");
        }
        else{
            console.log("user inserted");
        }
    })
};

module.exports = router;
```

**Model**

this is my user schema `user.js`

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name : { type: String },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  phoneNo: { type: Number },
  address: { type: String }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema, 'users');
```

Comment: `exports` is not returned by require(), use `module.exports.signup` instead of `exports.signup` in `./server/routes/api.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using exports and module.exports.
Either you should follow @dimagolovin's answer
OR
module.exports = {router};

and use

`app.use('/api', api.router);

app.post('/sign-up', api.signup);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the follwing in `./server/routes/api.js`

```
function signup(req, res, next){
console.log("new user entered");

var newUser = new User();
newUser.name = req.body.name;
 newUser.email = req.body.email;
 newUser.password = req.body.password;
 newUser.phoneNo = req.body.phone;
 newUser.address = req.body.address;

newUser.save(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log("error saving user");
    }
    else{
        console.log("user inserted");
    }
  })
};

module.exports = {router, signup};
```

It should do the work

Comment: i did the above change. Now i am getting another error. `Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object at function.use`

Comment: can you post the error? what @Arif Kahn  suggested is good too

Comment: after above changes, use `app.use('/api', api.router);` in `server.js`